# Window-scrolling suddenly began to “drag”. What should I do?

Tags: windows-xp, scrolling

Suddenly, it happened so that on my laptop whenever I scroll the window down or up it kind of began to drag. It doesn’t scroll as smoothly as it used to be. It kind of gets stuck for some fractions of a second and then jumps down. It looks as if the were not enough oil between the window and the screen, so instead of scrolling up and down smoothly it gets stuck every one tenth of a second. What should I do in order to fix it? It happens on all the browsers.

I am using Windows XP

Edit 1:

(This is my reply to **drew010**)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Start -> Run, and type devmgmt.msc.  Look under Display Adapters and see if your graphics driver is installed and working properly.  It sounds like you lost the graphics driver for some reason.  Can you tell if your screen resolution is lower as well?

UPDATE:
I think the one with the yellow question mark that says (VGA chinse chars) is the missing graphics driver.  Try right clicking on that and choosing the first option in the list which should be (update driver software).  It may be able to automatically install it.  If not, find out the make and model of the laptop, and you can download the driver from the manufacturer's support website.  Hopefully their installer would be english and easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have typed "devmgmt.msc" in there and here is what I've got (please see Edit 1 section in my question). Can you, please, help me as to which icon I should click on there. I am using a Chinese laptop, so it's all in Chinese there, but I don't understand Chinese. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer to try to help you out more.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also please tell me how to find out the make and the model of the laptop. Should it be written on he laptop or I can find it out by clicking some tabs/buttons on the screen?

Comment: Usually the model is on a sticker on the bottom of the laptop if they haven't been removed.  The manufacturer name is probably printed on the case somewhere.  The model may be around the bezel of the screen or near the keyboard sometimes too.  If the laptop is sold in china then the stickers may all have the model in chinese too.

Comment: If it just happened recently, it is possible to try a system restore to an earlier date when you know things were working.  But I would only try this if you are unable to locate the correct video driver or get it to automatically install from device manager.  In some cases, a missing graphics driver like that can also be a sign of malware, but not necessarily.